# How to get confusion matrix and ROC curve when using flow_from_directory?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I've trained a model using:

```
    train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1/255,
                                       zoom_range=0.3,
                                       shear_range=0.3,
                                       horizontal_flip=True,
                                       rotation_range=30,
                                       fill_mode="nearest",
                                       validation_split = 0.2)
    
    test_datagen  = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255
                                      )



    train_dataset  = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(directory = './train',
                                                       target_size = tsize,
                                                       class_mode = 'categorical',
                                                       subset = 'training',
                                                       batch_size = BS)
    
    valid_dataset = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(directory = './train',
                                                      target_size = tsize,
                                                      class_mode = 'categorical',
                                                      subset = 'validation',
                                                      batch_size = BS)
    
    test_dataset = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(directory = './test',
                                                      target_size = tsize,
                                                      class_mode = 'categorical',
                                                      batch_size = BS)
```

and also:

```
    hist = model.fit(train_dataset,validation_data=valid_dataset,epochs=30,callbacks=[vgg_step_1])
```

How can i plot confusion matrix?, im confused, i only have the validation vs train plot.

Answer (score 2):

To get a confusion matrix you need to make predictions on the test set. Then you need to provide the predicted values and the associated true values to the confusion matrix. Note -- in your code for the test_dataset you MUST set shuffle=False in flow_from_directory!!
Code below should generate an adaptable confusion matrix plot and classification report. model is your trained model.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.pyplot import imshow
import seaborn as sns
sns.set_style('darkgrid')
def cm_cr(test_gen, model):
    preds=model.predict(test_gen)    
    labels=test_gen.labels
    classes=list(test_gen.class_indices.keys()) # ordered lst of class names 
    pred_list=[ ] # will store the predicted classes here
    true_list=[]
    for i, p in enumerate (preds):
        index=np.argmax(p)
        pred_list.append(classes[index])
        true_list.append(classes[labels[i]])
    y_pred=np.array(pred_list)
    y_true=np.array(true_list)
    clr = classification_report(y_true, y_pred, target_names=classes)
    print("Classification Report:\n----------------------\n", clr)
    cm = confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred )        
    length=len(classes)
    if length<8:
        fig_width=8
        fig_height=8
    else:
        fig_width= int(length * .5)
        fig_height= int(length * .5)
    plt.figure(figsize=(fig_width, fig_height))
    sns.heatmap(cm, annot=True, vmin=0, fmt='g', cmap='Blues', cbar=False)       
    plt.xticks(np.arange(length)+.5, classes, rotation= 90, fontsize=16)
    plt.yticks(np.arange(length)+.5, classes, rotation=0, fontsize=16)
    plt.xlabel("Predicted")
    plt.ylabel("Actual")
    plt.title("Confusion Matrix")
    plt.show()

cm_cr(test_dataset, model)
```

I did not do the ROC curve but there is a good tutorial [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_roc.html) for that activity.